# How to set the first value of of a control to be the default value for parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a cascading control and I want the first value to be selected automatically after parent control value is selected by user. Or at least to reset the child control's values after another pick in parent control.

To rephrase this I would like to achieve a behavior of parent dropdown control to display value that is well human readable (let's call it name), but pass value to parameter that is easier to work with (let's call it id). I created such dropdowns in smaller dash web application, so I think it shouldn't be such an issue to implement, but I can't find a way to do this in AWS QS.

Is there any way to achieve this type of behavior? Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it is not possible to set parameter to another value than it has in control in QS yet. Will use some kind of compromise between what is still humanly readable and can be used for further processing.

Comment: Hey Kubo - this should have been left as a comment on your original question rather than an answer.